# Why is this for loop throwing a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing the method to draw a full circle in a numpy array of pixels, and I just don't understand why I am getting a TypeError. I apologize in advanced - I am a new Python programmer who recently switched from Java and I am still having trouble with all of this "lack-of-defining-variable-data-type-ing".

```
class Image:

    def drawCircle(self, centerX, centerY, radius):
        sin45 = 0.70710678118                                               
        distance = radius/(2*sin45)
        for i in range(radius,distance,-1.0): ####This is the error line####
            j = math.sqrt(r*r - i*i)
            for k in range(-j, j, 1):
                self.writePixel(self.centerX - k, self.enterY + i)
                self.writePixel(self.centerX - k, self.enterY - i)
                self.writePixel(self.centerX + i, self.enterY + i)
                self.writePixel(self.centerX - i, self.enterY - i)

'''Testing the code'''
obj = Image()
obj.drawCircle(35.0, 35.0, 35.0)
```

This code may be filled with other errors, but as of right now I am stumped on "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". Also, for the sake of saving space I have left the definition for writePixel() out, but just assume that it works. Thanks!

Comment: `range` cannot accept float, `radius` and `distance` might be floats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```py
for i in range(radius,distance,-1.0):
```

To:

```py
for i in range(int(radius),int(distance),int(-1.0)):
#or
for i in range(int(radius),int(distance),-1):
```

It should be noted that this will round those numbers down so if you need the precision of a decimal you should consider using a `linspace` from `numpy` instead of a `range`.

Also this will only fix the `TypeError`, not saying this will fix other issues

Comment: This is almost certainly what's causing the error. Worth noting, no need to bring `numpy` into it - if you need to round to the nearest whole number (and not just strictly *down*) you can probably just use the built-in `round()` function instead of `int()`

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in range function should be integer not a float. I guess that is causing issue. Please try using -1 instead of -1.0 , also convert radius and distance to int.

Answer (score -1):

In your code your are using variable `r` without defining it.

Try using `int(math.sqrt())`

Comment: That wouldn't be a `TypeError`.

Comment: Also check for math.sqrt statement it will return float so use int(math.sqrt())